# Error Running Code Analysis in VS2012: Could not resolve type reference

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

When I click the `Run Code Analysis` project context menu item. Building starts, but stops with following error:

```
CA0001  Error Running Code Analysis 
CA0001 : The following error was encountered while reading module 'EntityFramework': 
Could not resolve type reference: 
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute.   [Errors and Warnings]   (Global)
```

Analysis on other projects works well. How to eliminate this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations dll may not be used by your application but it is internally referenced by EntityFramework.dll.  Code Analysis will look at all of your referenced dll's and try to resolve their references too.  If you add the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll to your application, this error will go away next time you run Code Analysis.

Comment: I've try to add System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations dll to references, but it has not helped

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution mentioned by Scott Wylie. I tried adding a reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations in my project but that did not help.

I then tried copying and pasting the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll directly into my bin folder and that did the trick. Add the dll into your local bin folder, publish the solution, then manually add the dll into the bin folder of your published project (if it didn't copy up on its own).